# DRF update a row

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

im trying to update a existing row in db in client side i send request with put method to server i used `updatemodelmixin` also id is comming to server in data by this view server response is

`maximum recursion depth exceeded`

what is correct way to update my data?

```
class ProductOwnserSingleViewAPIView(APIView,mixins.UpdateModelMixin):

    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer

    def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return  self.put(self,request,*kwargs,**kwargs)

    def get(self, request):
        id = request.GET.get("id")
        try:
            product = Product.objects.get(
                author_id=request.user.id,
                product_id=id
            )
            if not product:
                return Response(status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
            serializer = ProductSerializer(instance=product, context={"request": request})
            return Response(serializer.data)
        except Product.DoesNotExist:
            return Response(status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: Your `put` results in an infinite loop.

Comment: For partial updates it is customary to use PATCH instead of PUT. PUT is meant for creation or replacement of a resource with the payload sent. See [RFC 7231#4.3.4 for PUT](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231.html#section-4.3.4) and [RFC 5789 for patch](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You write:

```
class ProductOwnserSingleViewAPIView(APIView,mixins.UpdateModelMixin):

    # ...

    def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return  self.put(self,request,*kwargs,**kwargs)
```

In case you perform a `PUT` request, then that means that the `put(..)` function is called with some arguments. But what does your `put` function do? Indeed, it calls *itself* with the very same parameters. This call subsequently results into another call, so you keep calling until the call stack reaches its maximum, and the the an error occurs.

A typical workflow for a `put(..)` is:

```
class ProductOwnserSingleViewAPIView(APIView,mixins.UpdateModelMixin):

    # ...

    def put(self, request, pk, format=None):
        # obtain the element we want to "update"
        product = Product.objects.get(
            author_id=request.user.id,
            product_id=request.GET('id')
        )

        # pass the element through the serializer with the data to update
        serializer = ProductSerializer(product, data=request.data)
        # check if the update makes sense (is valid)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            # if so, we save the object
            serializer.save()
            # and return the data as a response
            return Response(serializer.data)
        # if not, we report the errors as a response
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

So we first obtain the element we wish to `PUT`, then we call the serializer that will update the fields that we want to change (data is in the `request.data`), and finally in case all those fields are valid we save the object and return all the data of the object.

In case the serializer reports errors, we return those errors as a result.

Comment: thankyou for answer what is this err that say :
'ProductOwnserSingleViewAPIView' object has no attribute 'get_object'

Comment: @finfin: aarrgh... I think you probably should look through the documentation and look for views with more tooling.

Answer (score 0):

```
def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    return  self.put(self,request,*kwargs,**kwargs)
```

Change it;

```
def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    return  super(ProductOwnserSingleViewAPIView, self).update(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: thankyou i tried but i get error 
'ProductOwnserSingleViewAPIView' object has no attribute 'get_object'
 idk why